# Progressively building a large text chunk and then writing it to a file

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to Common Lisp and am trying to conceive of the best way to generate a large text file. I see basically two options:

1. Create a string and constantly add to it, then write this string to
   a file output stream just once, only at the final end of my iterations
2. Create a file stream and continually write to it over and over again as the program builds the text file

Perhaps similar to 1 would be:
 3. Create a string output stream and write to that, then write this stream to a new file stream.

The problem with 1 & 3 is that I don't think strings are designed to hold very large text contents, are they?

The problem with 2 is that it seems wasteful to constantly open and close a file, even if doing so conveniently with a `with-` command; seems inefficient and potentially error prone.

What is the typical way this is done?

Comment: What seems inefficient about 2?  Isn't that how logging is typically done?

Comment: If you do 1, though, and you have some idea of how big the content will be, you can make the string big enough from the beginning (and in fact, you could combine this with 3;  you can create a string output stream that writes to a particular string), and then write it out at the end.

Comment: It's about reading a file, not writing one, but you might be interested in an article about reading the contents of a file _into_ a string, [Slurping a file in Common Lisp](http://www.ymeme.com/slurping-a-file-common-lisp-83.html).  Some of the block-based IO might provide some insight here.  E.g., if you created a big string, you could write it with [`write-sequence`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_seq.htm#write-sequence). That article found that `read-sequence` was the quickest way to read the contents of a file;  maybe `write-sequence` will be good for writing.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor perhaps my worries are not a big deal if indeed strings can handle very large sizes. Is there a practical limit to the size of a string or a string output stream? With a file, you wouldn't expect this problem, but if I'm going to generate many files, and each file needs to be opened and closed with every single line of text in that file (because of the text generation algorithm), I would think doing all the file writing just once from a very big string is wiser, if strings can handle large sizes.

Comment: You wouldn't need to open and close the files, though, right?  Couldn't you open the file and keep it open until you're done with it?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor well, you got me there. I could organize things such that might be possible. I'm generating a collection of related files and sometimes writing the same parts of each file at the same time is convenient before moving on to other parts, hence the opening and closing frequently.

Comment: If nothing else, you could have a hash table mapping pathnames to streams.  Just pull up the stream as you need it, write some stuff, then move on to the next task.  Just be sure to close them all afterward. :)

Comment: A quick `(time
   (with-open-file (s "test.txt" :direction :output :if-does-not-exist :create :if-exists :append)
     (format s "Test string")))` gives me an average of 270-300 microseconds. IMO, you should measure first before trying to optimise something that might not be a problem. Open and close first. If that's too slow, keep the stream open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file stream and just keep it open for all your work, then close it and move onto another stream if necessary. No need to constantly reopen and close the file.